# SQLite SELECT not returning anything

Tags: sql, sqlite

This works to return a name:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE dno = 4 AND Ssn = 999887777;
```

returns the employee's name.

But this returns nothing:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE dno = 4 AND Ssn = (SELECT essn FROM WORKS_ON);
```

I want to get the names of all employees in Dept. No. 4 whose employee SSNs are found in the WORKS_ON table.

'essn' and 'Ssn' are both 9-character text fields that work in other contexts.

Comment: What happens when you run this query `SELECT essn FROM WORKS_ON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `=` to compare a value to a subquery that returns multiple values.

The way to figure out if `Ssn` is in the result of the subquery is to use `IN`:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE dno = 4 
  AND Ssn IN (SELECT essn FROM WORKS_ON);
```

Comment: D'oh! Works perfectly. THANK YOU